# Get the relation type between two Facebook friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm building a "Clue" like kind of game where you have to find which friend of yours is the criminal with some clues to help you.

I am trying to find a way to know the kind of relation between the user and a friend I picked up in the friends list; are they friends, family, accointance ? I can't find any information about this in the API documentation and ask myself if there is some other way to find it.

Here is my current request if it can help you...

```
$criminal_infos = $facebook->api(array(
        'method'=>'fql.query',
        'locale'=>'fr_CA',
        'query'=>'SELECT sex,relationship_status,education,current_location FROM user WHERE uid='.$criminal_id.''
    ));
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by requesting access to their friendlists and then seeing of the user ID in question is in a friendlist for Family or close friends etc.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/

Comment: Can I specify a user ID and get in what list the user is? Or do I have to scan all lists?

Comment: I believe you have to retrieve each friendlist and scan each list for the specific user ID. This would be more efficient than requesting the api for each friendlist user pair state. I.e. 1 request per friendlist no matter how many friends you need to scan? Otherwise you may hit the limit for api requests for your app.